# I keep getting a called object 'is_prime' is not a function and I don't know why

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that finds prime numbers and calls a function. However I keep getting a singular error that says the called object 'is_prime' is not a function in line 22. I set up a prototype but it still doesn't work. Help!

```
#include<stdio.h> 

double is_prime(int x);

int main()
{

    double is_prime;
    double primenum = 0;
    int n=0;
    int x=0;

    printf("Enter the value of n: ");       //getting length//
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n Printing primes less than or equal to %d: \n", n);   //message//

    for(x = 2; x <= n; x++)             //loop to check and print prime #s//
    {
        primenum = is_prime(x);    <------------line 22
        if (primenum == 1)
        { printf("%d, ",x); }
    }
return 0;
}

double is_prime(int x)
{

    int i=0;

    for (i = 2; i < x; i++) // this is the loop to check all numbers//
                        // under n to see if prime//
    {
        if (x==2)
            { return 1;}
        if ((x%i) == 0)
            {return 1;}
        else
            {return 0;}
    }

}
```

Comment: delete `double is_prime;`

Comment: Please use `-Wshadow` to spot that instead of asking here. Isn't it obvious that `double is_prime;` makes `is_prime` not a function? I think probably `python` allows this kind of thing and then you get used to it though it's wrong because even if it worked, it's quite confusing.

Comment: May I ask why you put that declaration there in the first place?

Comment: I'm learning all this for the first time and when I started writing the code I knew I had to declare it but I messed up the position hence why it was in the main function. Over rewriting the code I had forgotten about it and kept glossing over it when looking for my error. Just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared a variable with the same name as the function:

```
double is_prime;
```

This shadows the name of the function from the point of the declaration to the end of the scope of `main`.

Use a different name for either, or remove the declaration above, since you don't seem to need it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Deleting it fixed it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You define `double is_prime;`, so `is_prime` becomes a double, not a function.